# How to connect MouseDoubleClick to ViewModel in an Attached Behavior?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, calendar, attachedbehaviors

I am trying to implement Attached Behaviors functionality in the MVVM pattern.  I have a `Calendar` control and would like to handle the `MouseDoubleClick` event. I was doing that using System.Windows.Interactivity and `Interaction.Triggers`.  However, I am also using `BlackoutDates` in the `Calendar` and double-clicking on a Blackout Date results in the last valid selected date being passed to the `MouseDoubleClick` method, not the date clicked on.

So I am now targeting the `CalendarDayButton`, which will get me the date clicked on, but CDB doesn't have `Commands`, so I need to use an Attached Behavior.  But I'm still not understanding how to get the `MouseDoubleClick` handler info into the ViewModel. My current code:

**View**

```
<Calendar HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,48,0,0" 
          SelectedDate="{Binding ReportDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          DisplayDateStart="{Binding ReportDateStart, Mode=OneTime}" 
          DisplayDateEnd="{Binding ReportDateEnd, Mode=OneTime}" 
          local:AttachedProperties.RegisterBlackoutDates="{Binding NoProdDates, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
            <Setter Property="local:AttachedBehaviors.IsValidDateSelected" 
                    Value="{Binding ValidDateSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
</Calendar>
```

**ViewModel**

```
...
private bool validDateSelected;

public bool ValidDateSelected
{
    get { return validDateSelected; }

    set
    {
        if (validDateSelected != value)
        {
            validDateSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ValidDateSelected");
        }
    }
}
...
```

**Attached Behaviors class**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace MDOD
{
    public class AttachedBehaviors : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsValidDateSelectedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsValidDateSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(AttachedBehaviors), 
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsValidDateSelectedChanged));


        public static bool GetIsValidDateSelected(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsValidDateSelectedProperty);
        }


        public static void SetIsValidDateSelected(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsValidDateSelectedProperty, value);
        }


        private static void OnIsValidDateSelectedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CalendarDayButton cdb = d as CalendarDayButton;

            if (cdb != null)
            {
                if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                {
                    cdb.MouseDoubleClick += cdb_MouseDoubleClick;
                }
                else
                {
                    cdb.MouseDoubleClick -= cdb_MouseDoubleClick;
                }
            }
        }


        private static void cdb_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // How do I get this info to the ViewModel?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a `DependancyProperty` for an `ICommand`.  The view would bind an `ICommand` implementation to that `DependancyProperty`.  Your handler could then invoke the bound command through the property.

Comment: @BradleyUffner that is the part I don't understand how to do.

Comment: Just create a new dependency property, like you did for `IsValidDateSelectedProperty `, except make it an `ICommand`.  You can then bind it to something in XAML, exactly like you do for a `Button`.  Then in the handler, just get the value of the property and call `Execute` on it.